# What does 'Content was saved as DRAFT' mean in Crafter Studio?

Tags: crafter-cms

What does this message mean while selecting all in-progress content in Crafter Studio?

> Content was saved as DRAFT. Some required fields may not be populated.
>   This can cause errors when previewed or deployed.

The publish button is not available. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Save as draft allows the user to save their work without having to complete all required fields.

Publishing is disabled for all content items that haven't had all required fields populated, since publishing those can break the project/site.